# Filtering records on the basis of TTL

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

In my DynamoDb table I have set TTL column name to be "ttl".  I am using below mentioned Java code to apply filter on ttl but getting exception.   "Invalid FilterExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: ttl (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2;"   Is there any other way i can apply filter on TTL column ?

```
            Map<String, Object> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            String key = ":ttlvalue";
            expressionAttributeValues.put(key, 1614643859);
            query.withFilterExpression("ttl" + "=" + key);
            query.withValueMap(expressionAttributeValues);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use reserved keywords in Dynamo Expressions, we need to use a placeholder string and replace that string in NameMap

So,Instead of

```
.withFilterExpression("ttl = :v_ttl")
```

We can use

```
.withFilterExpression("#ttl_key = :v_ttl")
```

with

```
.withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#ttl_key","ttl"))
```

To replace `#ttl_key` with `ttl`

Here is a full example on table with partition key as 'pk' and ttl column.

```
Table table = dynamodB.getTable("test");        
QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec()
        .withKeyConditionExpression("pk = :v_pk")
        .withFilterExpression("#ttl_key = :v_ttl")
        .withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#ttl_key","ttl"))
        .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":v_pk", "5").withNumber(":v_ttl", 100));

ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(querySpec);
Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next().toJSONPretty());
}
```